# Get a value of similar XML tags using Regex

Tags: .net, xml

I would like to get the value of XML tags with similar name:

`<home:Phone>0228548979</home:Phone>`

`<phone>0265656565</phone>`

I  can get the value of `<phone>` if I use this Regex : `(?<=<phone>).*(?=</phone>)`

But I need the value of both element as long as they have `phone` in the tag, **case insensitive**.

Comment: Generally speaking, it's not a good idea to parse xml/html with regex. If possible, you should use xpath.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not gonna work as my use case requires to use Regex .